# Android layout with view fixed to bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a layout in Andorid. I need a TextView (2 in diagram below) fixed to the bottom of the screen. With content (1 in diagram) comprising of scrollview and editTexts.

The problem I have is when the soft keyboard comes up (3 in diagram), the red box marked 2 also comes up, above the keyboard. I would like the red box to remain offscreen and the entire content to scroll in the space remaining above the soft keyboard.

I've tried putting the red box (2) in the LinearLayout but it never fixes itself to the bottom, there's always a small gap at the bottom of the screen. I've also tried changing android:windowSoftInputMode in the manifest but this isn't the desired affect.

This is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText />
            <EditText />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/3"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         text="3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Illustration of android layout problem]

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why not just change box2's visibility to GONE when keyboard appears?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is switch your activity's windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan". Check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for more info.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: Now there is no scroll?

Comment: Try playing with some of the settings in the link I supplied for you. You can also set more than one item using the | modifier like so:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below layout see if this is what you are looking for..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/ed1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/ed2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="this is 3rd view"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

TL;DR version, i just removed two lines in your scrollview code:

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

with

```
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

See if that helps!

And any reason why you are using both **android:layout_alignParentTop="true"**
    **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**  on scrollview?

Comment: @James did you tried my answer?! is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks for trying Droidwala but this didn't help.

Comment: It was working well on my phone as per your requirement..so thought would help..did you tried implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea that works.

1. Adjust the layout so that the red box (2) is *inside* the LinearLayout
2. Create a small view between the red box and the last EditText
3. Give the red box and the LinearLayout an id, so we can manage them from the java class.

Your xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText />
            <EditText />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/stretcher"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/2"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                text="2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your java onActivityCreated add this code:

```
    final View mainLayout = getView();
    final View mainContent = getView().findViewById(R.id.content);
    final View stretcherView = getView().findViewById(R.id.stretcher);

    //Main layout uses weight some, so we can't hard code the size of the circles.
    //We must dynamically re-size
    mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            //Calculate the desired height of the stretcher view to be the remainder between full screen and content.
            int stretchHeight = mainLayout.getHeight() - mainContent.getHeight();

            //Apply calculated height remainder to stretched view.
            //This enables our bottom box to be pushed to the bottom without obstructing the content when the keyboard appears.
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) stretcherView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = stretchHeight;
            stretcherView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    });
```

The view listener measures the height of the full view then subtracts the height of the content. This leaves us with the gap between the content and the bottom of the screen. Using the stretcher view we can now push the red box down to the bottom of the page, just as if it was alignParentBottom.
When the keyboard appears, the red box is inside the scroll.